# Help with rails nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, nested-forms

I have these three models.

Student.
Evaluation.
Grade (student_id, evaluatioin_id, value)

I want to make a form so that a User can set the grade for each student of a evaluation...

I want to keep this is as clean as possible (and restful)...

Im open to any suggestions on how to get this done.

Please Help.

Comment: Did you set the associations between those models or not? If yes, please provide the code for each model.

Comment: Yes, the associations are set... What I want is a suggestion on form/view handling of this... I know how to accept nested attributes but I dont think that adding the grades in new/create/edit of the evaluation is elegant at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was..

In Grade Model

```
scope :for_student,lambda{|student, evaluation| where("student_id"=>student.id).where("evaluation_id"=>evaluation.id)}
```

In EvaluationsController

```
def assign_grades])
    @evaluation = Evaluation.find(params[:id])
    @students = Student.all  
    @students.each do |s|
      grade = Grade.for_student(s,@evaluation)
      if !grade.exists?  
       @evaluation.grades.build(:value=> 0,:student_id=>s.id)       
      end   
    end
  end

  def save_grades
    @evaluation = Evaluation.find(params[:id])
    @evaluation.update_attributes(params[:evaluation])

    redirect_to [@evaluation.batch_subject, @evaluation]

  end
```

In View

```
<table class="medium">      
<thead>
   <tr>
   <th>name</th>
   <th>Grade</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <%=f.fields_for :grades do |g|%>
    <tr>
      <td><%=g.label :value,g.object.student.full_name%> <%= g.hidden_field :student_id%></td>
<td><%=g.text_field :value%></td>
</tr>
<%end%>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

See these

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have the following associations:

**Evaluation:**

```
class Evaluation < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :grades
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :grades
end
```

**Student:**

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :grades
end
```

**Grade:**

```
class Grade < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :student
   blongs_to  :evaluation
end
```

Regarding your comment I think you want to use the [nested_form_for](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/) gem made by Ryan Bates. It helps you add/delete dynamically nested attributes in your form, very efficiently. You can use it like this:

```
    <% nested_form_for @evaluation do |f| %>
      <% f.fields_for :grades do |gf| %>
        <%= gf.label 'Username of the student' %>
        <%= gf.collection_select(:student, :student_id, Student.All, :id, :username) %>    <br/>
        <%= gf.label :value %>
        <%= gf.text_field :value %> <br/>
        <%= gf.link_to_remove 'delete' %> <br/>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.link_to_add 'Add grade', :grades %> <br/>
      <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
```

Tell me if it works/fits your needs. I have been using this gem a lot these previous days.

Comment: That looks close to what I have... but that form is not displaying the NAME of the Student anywhere... how would I display the name of the student right before the input text field for his/her grade?

Comment: Take a look at my edit. I displayed the name of the student inside a select box.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.. the problem is that EVERY student must have a grade for each evaluation..  I dont actually need select Box. I just want a list of all the students with a text field next to each... so that I can set the value for that evaluation,student.

Comment: Ok, I see what you want (Although what I have proposed allows you to ADD a couple (student, grade) dynamically. So you can do that for each of your students). Let me think about it :).

Comment: Thanks man I appreciate it... I have been thinking about it for a few days now and I cant seem to find an elegant solution